# Use CKEDITOR's htmlDataProcessor to clean html

Tags: ckeditor, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I'd like to use the data processing module from CKEDITOR to clean up some html for display, but not use the gui or other features of CKEDITOR.

We have some really gnarly input html and I just want it to have symmetrical tags, strip inline position-based styles, and go from there.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this, probably because I don't know how to use CKEDITOR (it's used elsewhere in this app).

I've tried:

```
var data = CKEDITOR.dataProcessor.toDataFormat('<body><b>foo</b></b></body>'); // throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined(…)
var cleanedHtml = data.toHtml();
```

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dataProcessor

Comment: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlDataProcessor